# Using CAST in ORDER BY references sub query instead of main query

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to run a query on RedShift that takes the results of a subquery, buckets them into groups, and then shows the count for the groups in ascending order

```
WITH MonthlyAmountPerUser as ( 
    SELECT Month, UserId, SUM(Amount) as TotalAmount FROM AnotherTable
    GROUP BY UserId, Month
)
    
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN "TotalAmount" > 0 AND "TotalAmount" <= 500 THEN '0 - 500'
        WHEN "TotalAmount" > 500 AND "TotalAmount" <= 1000 THEN '500 - 1000'
        WHEN "TotalAmount" > 1000 AND "TotalAmount" <= 1500 THEN '1000 - 1500'
        WHEN "TotalAmount" > 1500 AND "TotalAmount" <= 2000 THEN '1500 - 2000'
        ELSE '20000 +'
    END AS MonthlyRange,
    count(*) AS MonthlyCount

FROM MonthlyAmountPerUser  
    
GROUP BY MonthlyRange
ORDER BY MonthlyRange ASC
```

This gives the correct results however, the "MonthlyRange" column is ordered as a string which ends up with the ordering

```
0 - 500
1000 - 1500
1500 - 2000
20000 +
500 - 1000
```

To get this to order correctly this I'm trying to cast the "MonthlyRange" column to a number which I would expect to change the ordering to

```
0 - 500
500 - 1000
1000 - 1500
1500 - 2000
20000 +
```

However when I change the ORDER BY statement to

```
ORDER BY CAST(MonthlyRange as INT) ASC
```

I get the error

```
Invalid operation: column "monthlyrange" does not exist in monthlyamountperuser
```

Why does RedShift try to look for a column inside of the subquery when I try to modify the column in the ORDER BY statement? How can I get it to reference the column that exists in my main query?

Answer (score 0):

You will need another `case..when` expression as follows:

```
ORDER BY CASE 
        WHEN  MonthlyRange = '0 - 500' then  1
        WHEN  MonthlyRange = '500 - 1000' then  2
        WHEN  MonthlyRange = '1000 - 1500' then  3
        WHEN  MonthlyRange = '1500 - 2000' then  4
        ELSE 5
    END
```

Comment: This gives the same error of ```the column montlyrange not existing in monthlyamountperuser```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using an aggregation function for the `ORDER BY`:

```
ORDER BY MIN("TotalAmount")
```

Comment: It seems that any function in the order by clause gives the same error, with this suggestion I get ```totalamount does not exist in montlyamountperuser```

Comment: @AshokFernandez . . . RedShift might have a non-standard limitation. 
 Try putting `MIN("TotalAmount")` in the `SELECT` with a new alias and sorting on the alias.